# Detect IP address, converting it to a username and displaying it on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using PHP and HTML I need to detect a user's IP address, if the IP address is a specific one, an alert box pops up and says "Welcome, ______!". 
Can I just set it up as an if, else, or something like that? 
I only have a few users (and it will stay that way), so I don't need anything elaborate. 
I can choose which IP address corresponds to which username that pops up, but how do I do all of this? 
And how do I get it into HTML format? I have a *pretty* solid understanding of alert boxes (javascript), but php, not so much. Can you please explain the steps in layman's terms?

Comment: Hahhaahhahaahah it's if else not if then what is wrong with me.

Comment: What's wrong is that I have no idea exactly what to do or where to start...

Comment: you need to do more research and improve your coding skills, I doubt anyone will help with this

Comment: Okay... :/ Thanks anyways...

Comment: Sorry, keep reading and learning, if you put the time in you'll get it

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. For now your question is considered off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your opening statement ‘I need this all in HTML format’ is not possible as you point out the requirement for PHP which is not HTML. It generally produces HTML, but it’s not HTML in itself.

To detect a users IP address:  Google search `php get ip address of client` and you will find a lot of info including some of the pitfalls on accuracy etc.

Where you want to put HTML or JavaScript in your document use something like:

```
<?php
  $clientIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  // now check if it’s a particular IP address. This if statement will only add the echoed html/javascript code if it is that IP address.
  If ($clientIP == “192.168.0.2”) {
    echo “Javascript/HTML code here to create your popup message between quotes”;
    // you can use multiple echo lines which is where you write javascript of html to create your html page
  }
  // repeat if statement for more IP’s or you can get fancy 
?>
```

A tip on using PHP for certain bits in a normal HTML document: Write the document as HTML and where you need to put something different because of (in this case) a specific IP address, put the PHP code there. Don’t forget to start the php code with a `<?php` and end it with a `?>`

**//** is a comment line in PHP

**$_SERVER** http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

**echo** is what it says, a built in PHP command that echoes what its told to. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php for details.

This is fairly basic to hopefully get you going. Start small and work your way up.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps! :D